Stake warmup and cooldown - is it possible to retrospectively get this information?
We are trying to retrospectively build staking activation/deactivation history for an account. In other words, we want to capture events which change amount of active and inactive stake. Some of them are explicit, like delegation/undelegation transactions, splitting/merging stake account, etc. There are no questions about them.
However, this specification explains how stakes are being gradually activated in case of certain amount (25% currently) of all stakes being requested to stake/unstake during a single epoch.
My question is - how can we get the information needed to rebuild this logic in our program? Meaning - total active stake at epoch N and total number of stakes requested to be activated/deactivated during that epoch? I only see brute force approaches - parse entire SOL blockchain history, or instrument the node's code to write these values. Is there more intelligent solution?
To reiterate - all we need to know are "implicit" changes in active/inactive stake of the account, which happen at epoch boundary. Unfortunately, there is no API which would provide that information for historical periods. getStakeActivation API would be a perfect place to obtain such information if it supported epoch parameter. Unfortunately, it does not:
epoch u64 optional

epoch for which to calculate activation details. If parameter not provided, defaults to current epoch.
DEPRECATED, inputs other than the current epoch return an error.


OK, found an answer. You send the following request:
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 1,
"method": "getAccountInfo",
"params": [
"SysvarStakeHistory1111111111111111111111111",
{"encoding": "base64"}
]
}
'
Decode response from base64 and read values from it. All values are in u64 little-endian. First goes number of entries, then entries in format of 4 u64 numbers:
epoch number
total number of staked lamports
number of lamports requested to be activated
number of lamports requested to be deactivated
